# What are some of the characteristics of database architecture used by highly trafficked login pages (gmail, facebook, twitter)?

Tags: mysql, sql

For small-sized publicly facing websites using a `UNIQUE` index on an `email_address` field would help speed up queries.

```
SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE email_address = ?
  AND hash_password = ?
```

For a large scale public-facing website this seems far too simplistic.

What are some of the characteristics of the database architecture used by much larger, highly trafficked websites for the specific task of authentication of unique emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem that you are facing?

You should have indexes and keys no matter how many rows you have/queries you do. If you have that - you should be fine for a regular page/app.

Monitor the performance. When your user base grows and you start experiencing problems with performance - identify them and deal with the thing that's slowing you down.

Usually it's not the volume, but complexity, that brings performance down. Or more like `volume*complexity`. So if you have simple system - you should be fine.